# SQL/PLSQL Oracle query: CASE in WHERE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am attempting to query an oracle db but cant quite get the script to work. The script is meant to search for employees with a `start_date` between two dates. Unfortunately, not all employees have a `start_date` in the database, but all employees have a `create_date`. What I would like to do is:

```
IF START_DATE IS NULL:
    (E.START_DATE >= TO_DATE('10/29/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND E.START_DATE <= TO_DATE('10/29/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
ELSE: 
    (E.CREATE_DATE >= TO_DATE('10/29/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND E.CREATE_DATE <= TO_DATE('10/29/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT OC.DESCRIPTION "Description",
sum(S.AMOUNT) "SUM",
COUNT (DISTINCT(E.EMPLOYEE_NUM)) "Employee Nums"
FROM EMPLOYEES E
JOIN EMPLOYEE_SPENDING S ON S.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE E.EMPLOYEE_CATEGORY IN ('ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE')
AND ((E.START_DATE >= TO_DATE('10/29/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND E.START_DATE <= TO_DATE('10/29/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
OR (E.CREATE_DATE >= TO_DATE('10/29/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND E.CREATE_DATE <= TO_DATE('10/29/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY')))
GROUP BY E.EMPLOYEE_CATEGORY;
```

My case statement looked something like this:

```
SELECT OC.DESCRIPTION "Description",
sum(S.AMOUNT) "SUM",
COUNT (DISTINCT(E.EMPLOYEE_NUM)) "Employee Nums"
FROM EMPLOYEES E
JOIN EMPLOYEE_SPENDING S ON S.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE E.EMPLOYEE_CATEGORY IN ('ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE')
AND (CASE WHEN E.START_DATE IS NULL THEN (E.START_DATE >= TO_DATE('10/29/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND E.START_DATE <= TO_DATE('10/29/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
ELSE (E.CREATE_DATE >= TO_DATE('10/29/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND E.CREATE_DATE <= TO_DATE('10/29/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
END
GROUP BY E.EMPLOYEE_CATEGORY;
```

I'm not super familiar with Oracle or PLSQL, so any help you can provide would  be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do the queries not give you the results you expected? How do they behave? What would you have expected? Or is there any other problem?

Comment: It wont run, and tells I'm missing a parentheses...I can't find where that would be and have attempted multiple different places. I'm really just wondering if this is the correct way to do this, or if there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have the logic backwards.  This makes much more sense:

```
IF START_DATE IS NOT NULL:
    (E.START_DATE >= TO_DATE('10/29/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND E.START_DATE <= TO_DATE('10/29/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
ELSE: 
    (E.CREATE_DATE >= TO_DATE('10/29/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND E.CREATE_DATE <= TO_DATE('10/29/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Then, you can just express this as:

```
where (e.start_date >= date '2014-10-29' and e.start_date <= date '2016-10-29') or
      (e.start_date is null and e.create_date >= date '2014-10-29' and e.start_date <= date '2016-10-29')
```

Notice that I've simplified the "date constant" by using the `date` keyword followed by an ISO-standard date.

This can be further simplified as:

```
where coalesce(e.start_date, e.create_date) >= date '2014-10-29' and
      coalesce(e.start_date, e.create_date) <= date '2016-10-29'
```

In general, you want to avoid `case` in `where` clauses, because basic boolean expressions are usually pretty simple to write and understand.  The time to use `case` is when you explicitly want to sequence the conditions, particularly when one condition might be an expensive function call.

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you so much for breaking that down for me. I can't tell you how much I appreciate that. I'll be able to use this concept on a few other projects I'm working on as well. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use nvl like this:

```
SELECT OC.DESCRIPTION "Description",
sum(S.AMOUNT) "SUM",
COUNT (DISTINCT(E.EMPLOYEE_NUM)) "Employee Nums"
FROM EMPLOYEES E
JOIN EMPLOYEE_SPENDING S ON S.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE E.EMPLOYEE_CATEGORY IN ('ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE')
AND ((nvl(E.START_DATE, e.create_date) >= TO_DATE('10/29/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND (nvl(E.START_DATE, e.create_date) <= TO_DATE('10/29/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
GROUP BY E.EMPLOYEE_CATEGORY;
```

Comment: This will default to the createdate field if startdate is null - should accomplish what you need here

Comment: I'll give this a shot and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: `isnull()` is not an Oracle function.

Comment: use nvl() then?